# Rails modeling headache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oop, models

I am in the process of building a Rails app that will let logged-in users:

- create multiple agendas
- access each agenda through a "month" view
- add events to each month
- share each agenda (through a link) with other logged-in users, who will see it with the same default "month" view but will be able to access other months with the simple click of a previous/next button.

The first thing I am trying to do is defining Rails models, and here is my dilemma:

**1. Should I go with four models:**

- User model (has_many agendas)
- Agenda model (belongs to many users,
  has many months)
- Month model (belongs to one agenda, has many post)
- Post model (belongs to one month)

**2. *OR* should I go with three models:**

- User model (has_many agendas)
- Agenda model (belongs to many users, has many posts)
- Post model (belongs to one agenda)

Indeed, the months will not be specific to each agenda, but will only be a framework to display posts month per month in each agenda.

What do you think?

Comment: A Month should't be a model - it's a date-range... what if next week you need to display them grouped by quarter as well? or by year? Instead - month is just a date-range you should filter your view by.

Comment: Thanks @TarynEast. That's what I had in mind but was not sure about. The idea of filter the view by month is the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on whether you have many fields specific to agenda (not to month).
If you do, it's better to have one separate model for agenda.

BTW, It seems user and agenda are many-to-many relationship. In this case, you need one intermediate model between user and agenda.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @rxing. When you say that user and agenda are many-to-many relathionships and I need a third, intermediate model, do you refer to the "has_many :through" association as explained on http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html ?

Comment: From the db view, one intermediate table is needed for many-to-many relationship.Back to Rails, yes, you can use "has_many... through" so that you can use user.agendas and agenda.users.

Comment: Thank you very much @rxing. I understand the Rails part, and being able to use both user.agendas AND agenda.users is exactly what I want. However, I am not sure I get what you mean by: "From the db view, one intermediate table is needed for many-to-many relationship." May I ask you if you have any resource I could check on the topic?

Comment: You can check below link about db design first. http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=manymany.php

Comment: Thank you very much @rxing, I am going to dig into this.